# How to write csv file using common-csv lib

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I'm using common-csv to write a CSV file from a request body and I'm getting all the records in the same line and with double quotes:

```
Client Name,Value
"client 1,1.0","client 2,2.0","client 3,53.78","client 4,3.0","client 5555555,4.0","client 6,33.0","client 7,0.0","client 8,8.5"
```

What I need is:

```
Client Name, Value
"client 1", 1.0
"client 2", 2.0
"client 3", 53.78 (and so on)
```

this is the code (partial):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/csv")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> exportCSVV2(@RequestBody ClientDataObjectRequest clientDataObjectRequest){

        String[] csvHeader = {"Client Name","Value"};
        List<List<CompanyChartData>> csvBody = new ArrayList<>();
        csvBody.add(clientDataObjectRequest.getCompanyChartData());

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayOutputStream;

        try(
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(
                        new PrintWriter(out),
                        CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(csvHeader)
                );
        ) {

            for (List<CompanyChartData> record: csvBody) {
                csvPrinter.printRecord(record);

            }
            csvPrinter.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        InputStreamResource fileInputStream = new InputStreamResource(byteArrayOutputStream);

        String dateFile = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date());
        String timeFile = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm").format(new java.util.Date());
        String fileName = clientDataObjectRequest.getMetricName().replace(" ","_") + "_" + dateFile + "T" + timeFile;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".csv");
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/csv");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                fileInputStream,
                headers,
                HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
```

This code above is generating the response that I do not want. I've tried others stuff like changing the CSVFormat to another standard, also tried using the method "printRecords" instead of "printRecord". I did some research in the documentation but I'm struggling to understand it.

Comment: What does the request look like? How does it map to ClientDataObjectRequest?

Comment: Is a mapping a necessary thing? I cannot put here the request due limitation of space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Write CSV File with Apache.commons.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289043/java-write-csv-file-with-apache-commons-csv)

Comment: @MartinZeitler No, it does not answer but thanks anyway. BTW, I answered my on question. Please, check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to change the outcome.
Instead of using this way:

```
try(
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(
                        new PrintWriter(out),
                        CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(csvHeader)
                );
        ) {

            for (List<CompanyChartData> record: csvBody) {
                csvPrinter.printRecord(record);

            }
```

I changed to this approach:

```
try(
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(
                        new PrintWriter(out),
                        CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(csvHeader).withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NON_NUMERIC)
                );
        ) {

            for (CompanyChartData record: csvBody) {
                csvPrinter.printRecord(record.getClientName(), record.getValue());

            }
```

And the response was

```
"Client Name","Value"
"client 1",1.0
"client 2",2.0
"client 3",53.78
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and the result coming from the `printRecord` method  my first guess would be is that your request mapping is incorrect.

According to the documentation of the `printRecord` method it will:

> Prints the given values a single record of delimiter separated values followed by the record separator.

Looking at the code above it's just performing a for loop until there are no more values in the collection before it prints a new line.

```
for (final Object value : values) {
    print(value);
}
println();
```

According to the output given above that would mean that `List<CompanyChartData> record` in your for loop is a list that contains an Object that contains the all values coming from the request instead of a list of objects that contains your key value pairs.

My assumption would be that if you put a `System.out.println` statement in the for loop or attach a debugger it should it will only print once.

Comment: Actually, what I do need is that the string is between double quotes and the number without it. I'll edit the main question.